Why is the upgrade from 23.04 to 24.04.1 failing with "install all available updates"?
The upgrade to 24.04.1 is failing with a message that I need to make all updates before installing.  As you can see in the attached log, I've attempted to make all updates however some 'esm-apps' updates are not being installed and I need to install Ubuntu Pro to update them.  I am assuming these updates are not required to do the update.
There is a series of dotnet updates that are not installed, but I previosly removed dotnet. Are these the updates that is blocking the upgrade?  If yes, can I get rid of them?
As an aside, I also tried the Software Updater and it exits without a message. :-(
Regards
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                 
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                          
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                             
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                         
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease           
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy InRelease        
Hit:9 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:10 https://hub-dist.unity3d.com/artifactory/hub-debian-prod-local stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.


$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libheif1 libjs-jquery-ui libpathplan4 graphviz libgvpr2 libgvc6 libopenexr25
  python3-scipy libcgraph6 libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libcdt5
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 imagemagick-6.q16 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 liblab-gamut1
  imagemagick-6-common libde265-0 libpmix2
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  dotnet-hostfxr-7.0 ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-pro-client ubuntu-pro-client-l10n
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.


$ do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

$ sudo apt list --upgradeable -a
Listing... Done
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.0.119-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 7.0.5-1]
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.20-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.19-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.18-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.17-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.16-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.15-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.14-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.13-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.12-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.11-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.10-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.9-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.8-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.7-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy,now 7.0.5-1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 7.0.119-0ubuntu1~22.04.1]
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.4-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.3-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.2-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.1-1 amd64
dotnet-hostfxr-7.0/jammy 7.0.0-1 amd64

$ sudo apt remove dotnet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'dotnet' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.


Upgrade from 23.04 to 24.04 is not supported at all, you can't skip releases. Please take a look at this question. You'd have to upgrade to 23.10 (which is also end of life) first. I'd recommend to perform a fresh install of 24.04.

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release? and Can I skip over releases when upgrading?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I see jammy in your pasted details; so I suggest checking your facts. jammy is the codename for 22.04, with lunar being the codename for 23.04.  This comment is the only mention of lunar on this page currently.




I've attempted to make all updates however some 'esm-apps' updates are not being installed and I need to install Ubuntu Pro to update them.

You have misread the output. Ubuntu Pro ('esm-apps') is not required.




The reason your system will not release upgrade is...
The following packages have been kept back:
  dotnet-hostfxr-7.0 ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-pro-client ubuntu-pro-client-l10n
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

...phased updates.
The safest course is to simply let phasing complete. Maybe a few days. Maybe a week. Then those packages (except dotnet-hostfxr-7.0) will install, and then you can release-upgrade.
If you really want to, you can override phasing and install them now. How to do so has been explained many times, so I'll let you search for it if you want to go that route.




Your dotnet issue seems simple enough:
The package name is dotnet-hostfxr-7.0
But you wrote $ sudo apt remove dotnet
Try using the complete package name: $ sudo apt remove dotnet-hostfxr-7.0


